# No META-INF/persistence.xml was found in classpath

Tags: java, jpa, netbeans, persistence, persistence.xml

I'm using netbeans 6.8 and the Persistence API.

In netbeans 6.8 the persistence.xml is placed in the src/conf/ folder.
I've tried creating a /src/META-INF/ folder and copying the persistence.xml in that folder but I still get the error

No META-INF/persistence.xml was found in classpath.

When trying to run the application.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the root of the META-INF folder is on your classpath when you run the application.  (the src directory will not be on the classpath, only the directory where NetBeans compiles the classes to).

Comment: 5 years later, I'm encountering the same problem. How do I do that in netbeans?